# How can I style a PHP echo text?

Tags: php, css, styling

I have the following code;

```
<?php
    function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
    {
        $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=5cfaab6c5af420b7b0f88d289571b990763e37b66761b2f053246f9db07ca913&ip=$ipAddr&format=json";
        $d = file_get_contents($url);
        return json_decode($d , true);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
       $ip = countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);

       //print_r($ip);
       echo $ip['cityName'];
       echo $ip['countryName'];
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ip" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

I need to style "echo $ip['cityName']" here. I tried a lot methods, but I am only getting an error.

Comment: what is the error? undefined index?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I need to style "echo..."'?

Comment: This makes no sense. You output data from the server and you style the data for the clients. Don't mix those! Try to use a PHP template engine or start replacing strings in your template. This will be better practice in the future.

Comment: I already got the answer I was looking for

Comment: Can you help me to center this text box, 'code' <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form> 'code'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can style it by the following way:

```
echo "<p style='color:red;'>" . $ip['cityName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p style='color:red;'>" . $ip['countryName'] . "</p>";
```

Comment: Can you help me to center this text box;

Comment: use <center><input type="text" name="ip" /></center> - to get centered the textbox

Answer (score 9):

Echo inside an HTML element with `class` and style the element:

```
echo "<span class='name'>" . $ip['cityName'] . "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "style echo" with adding new HTML code.

```
echo '<span class="city">' . $ip['cityName'] . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<span style="Your CSS Styles">' . $ip['cityName'] . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your results in variables, and use them in your HTML and add the necessary styling.

```
$usercity = $ip['cityName'];
$usercountry = $ip['countryName'];
```

And in the HTML, you could do:

```
<div id="userdetails">
<p> User's IP: <?php echo $usercity; ?> </p>
<p> Country: <?php echo $usercountry; ?> </p>
</div>
```

Now, you can simply add the styles for `country` class in your CSS, like so:

```
#userdetails {

/* styles go here */

}
```

Alternatively, you could also use this in your HTML:

```
<p style="font-size:15px; font-color: green;"><?php echo $userip; ?> </p>
<p style="font-size:15px; font-color: green;"><?php echo $usercountry; ?> </p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @thomas: What do you mean it's not working? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style a variable such as $ip['countryName']

You can only style elements like p,div, etc, or classes and ids.

If you want to style $ip['countryName'] there are several ways.

You can echo it within an element:

```
echo '<p id="style">'.$ip['countryName'].'</p>';
echo '<span id="style">'.$ip['countryName'].'</span>';
echo '<div id="style">'.$ip['countryName'].'</div>';
```

If you want to style both the variables the same style, then set a class like:

```
echo '<p class="style">'.$ip['cityName'].'</p>';
echo '<p class="style">'.$ip['countryName'].'</p>';
```

You could also embed the variables within your actual html rather than echoing them out within the code.

```
$city = $ip['cityName'];  
$country = $ip['countryName'];
?>
<div class="style"><?php echo $city ?></div>
<div class="style"><?php echo $country?></div>
```