# Should all files have the .php extension or should PHP output a string?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to show the server status of an IP address on every page, but to check the status I need a PHP script. This script is what I found on the Internet:

```
<?php
    $server = 'google.be:80';
    $split = explode(':', $server);
    $ip = $split[0];
    $port = (empty($split[1])) ? '80' : $split[1];
    $server = $ip . ':' . $port;

    $fp = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if($fp) {
        echo $server . ' is online';
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else {
        echo $server . ' is offline';
    }
?>
```

I want the echoes to be formatted like my CSS content is formatted, so I could just replace the echoes with:

```
?>
<p>Server is offline<p>
<?php
```

and

```
?>
<p>Server is online<p>
<?php
```

But then I would have to make every HTML file a PHP file. Would you recommend that or is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: I personally would have every file be a PHP file. On my server every file is a PHP file since it doesn't hurt to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jQuery AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) to send the PHP data to your HTML page. You could [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the response and receive that data as a JSON object and get the data out of it.

EDIT: In a production enviroment and for efficiency, it would be best if you convert the HTML files to PHP files, it will be worth the labour. However this little snippet below could be used for other functionality if modified or built upon so it's a learning experience for you to see basic jQuery AJAX calls.

The following code is a working example of calling your PHP file and getting back the result. Seeing a basic example of using jQuery and AJAX will help you get a firm grounding of how to use it.

**check_server.php**

```
<?php
    $server='google.be:80';
    $split=explode(':',$server);
    $ip=$split[0];
    $port=(empty($split[1]))?'80':$split[1];
    $server=$ip.':'.$port;
$fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);

   $result = new stdClass();
if($fp){
    $result->result = 'success';
    fclose($fp);
}
else{
   $result->result = 'offline';
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
        url : "check_server.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(results){
                      if (results.result === 'success')
                      {
                          $('#status').append('Server online.');
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         $('#status').append('Server offline.');
                      }
                  },
         error : function()
              {
                  $('#status').append('An error has occurred.');
              }
    });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is still something I can try, not sure if it's easier to use this or making every file .php

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx it's quite simple and a great tool to have for web development.

Comment: I'll see if I could learn ajax. I'm quite interested in seeing what it can do actually.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx it's a great tool for a responsive website, see my answer again to see a small working example, you can see how easy your solution is once you know how to use jQuery.

Comment: Alright I'll take a look at it, Thanks!

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx no problem, index.php was meant to be index.html by the way.

Comment: I agree that Ajax knowledge is important for web development and that this is a nice simple use case to learn the beginnings with - but don't you think this is a bit of overkill for this particular situation?

Comment: @Kvothe yes I do agree with you, I was thinking this solution would help OP not having to change his/her file types but if this is going to be in a production environment it is not efficient. If OP does have time it would be good to change the files over to PHP and echo the result. OP please see this and notice my recommendation changing to editing your HTML to PHP files if PHP input is needed for them. I will reflect the change in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation. I think that ajax and json are quite handy together and if you both think it is overkill for such an easy task, then I'll go with changing the HTML to PHP files. Would you use these kind of methods in webshops and other pages where there is a lot of information to get from an PHP file? Could you give me an example of when to use this?

Comment: Ajax is useful for situations where you want to update part of the page without reloading the entire page - e.g. reloading a table without reloading everything else on the page. If you want to learn more about Ajax then try the [W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Alrighty, Thank you for the information, I'll take a look at the link.

Answer (score 3):

On my server all the files are a PHP since I need to include PHP functions such as `echo` username and such, and I believe it doesn't hurt to convert .html to .php. Another thing is that the following page provides information on styling PHP `echo`es with CSS.

*[How can I style a PHP echo text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252433/how-can-i-style-a-php-echo-text)*

I think it would be better have all PHP files.

Comment: Styling every php individually will take way more time than just changing the extension, so I am going with that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement PHP in an HTML file. To create HTML in a .php file is the best solution to solve this.

You can use HTML in a PHP file and you do not have to use PHP in the file if you name it a PHP file.

Comment: I think I'll just be doing this